# Select key from jsonb postgreSQL using Hibernate Criteria query in Java

Tags: java, json, postgresql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am writing the criteria query to get results for jsonb in postgres.I can query the jsonb column through hibernate.I am unable to fetch jsonb specific keys.I am not able to find a way.

I have tried native query but i want some wayout in hibernate criteria query.The commonjson argument is the jsonb in postgresql is this --

```
{"appl_id": 726516, "applied_by": "pankajkumarnnl94@gmail.com", "service_id": 9880004, "version_no": 4, "appl_ref_no": "BSEH/2018/00728", "sub_version": 1, "payment_date": "2018-12-04T11:54:20.24+05:30", "payment_mode": "PayUbizz", "reference_no": "7726929249", "service_name": "Migration Certificate Board of School Education Haryana, Bhiwani", "department_id": 784, "location_value": 1218758, "base_service_id": 988, "department_name": " Board of School Education Haryana", "registration_id": "", "submission_date": "2018-12-04", "submission_mode": "online", "no_of_attachment": 2, "submission_location": "1578947~1218758~Board of School Education Haryana"}
```

Model Class ->ApplInfoJson

```
package com.saral.reporting.model;

import java.util.Map;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@Entity
@Table(name = "r_app_json",schema="saral1", catalog="saral1")

public class ApplInfoJson {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "aid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long aid;

    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @JsonProperty("appl_info")
    @Column(name = "appl_info")
    private String applInfo;


    @Column(name = "application_form_attributes")
    private String applicationFormAttributes;

    @Column(name = "enclosure_data")
    private String enclosureData;

    @Column(name = "service_id")
    private Long serviceId;

    @Column(name = "combined_json")
    @Type(type = "JsonDataUserType")
    private Map<String , Object> combinedJson;

    @Column(name ="location_value")
    private Long locationValue;


    public Long getLocationValue() {
        return locationValue;
    }

    public void setLocationValue(Long locationValue) {
        this.locationValue = locationValue;
    }

    public Long getServiceId() {
        return serviceId;
    }

    public void setServiceId(Long serviceId) {
        this.serviceId = serviceId;
    }

    public Long getAid() {
        return aid;
    }

    public void setAid(Long aid) {
        this.aid = aid;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getApplInfo() {
        return applInfo;
    }

    public void setApplInfo(String applInfo) {
        this.applInfo = applInfo;
    }

    public String getApplicationFormAttributes() {
        return applicationFormAttributes;
    }

    public void setApplicationFormAttributes(String applicationFormAttributes) {
        this.applicationFormAttributes = applicationFormAttributes;
    }

    public String getEnclosureData() {
        return enclosureData;
    }

    public void setEnclosureData(String enclosureData) {
        this.enclosureData = enclosureData;
    }




    public Map<String, Object> getCombinedJson() {
        return combinedJson;
    }

    public void setCombinedJson(Map<String, Object> combinedJson) {
        this.combinedJson = combinedJson;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ApplInfoJson [aid=" + aid + ", id=" + id + ", applInfo=" + applInfo + ", applicationFormAttributes="
                + applicationFormAttributes + ", enclosureData=" + enclosureData + ", serviceId=" + serviceId
                + ", combinedJson=" + combinedJson + ", locationValue=" + locationValue + "]";
    }



}
```

Function Used->

```
public List<ApplInfoJson> findByCombinedJson(String commonJson) {

        DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(ApplInfoJson.class);

        List<ApplInfoJson> results = (List<ApplInfoJson>) getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria);

        return results;

    }
```

I want some thing to pass key name and get data with specific key.

Comment: You can use functions which are available since JPA 2.1.

Comment: @Ancoron how can i do that ??

Comment: Use the standard [`CriteriaBuilder#function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#function-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-javax.persistence.criteria.Expression...-). Example: https://github.com/thjanssen/HibernateTips/blob/master/CriteriaCustomFunction/src/test/java/org/thoughts/on/java/model/TestCriteriaConstructor.java#L48

Comment: Thanks i have seen the code but i want to select appl_id from json .how can i do that @Ancoron

Comment: You need to use function [`json_extract_path_text(combined_json, 'appl_info')`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) (assuming that column `combined_json` contains the JSON. Translated into Criteria Query, this means something like: `cb.function("json_extract_path_text", String.class, root.get(ApplInfoJson_.combinedJson), "appl_info")`